# realloc() is not reallocating more memory

Tags: c

My realloc() is not reallocating more memory. For example, I have a method:

```
void addInfo(LocationArray** myArray, int* count, int* numberOfLoc) {

    if(*count == *numberOfLoc) { // Checks if the array is already full
        printf("count is %d and numberOfLoc is %d\n", *count, *numberOfLoc);
        resizeArray(*myArray, numberOfLoc); //Resizes the array if it's full
    }
    .......
}
```

If `count` value is equal to `numberOfLoc` then `resizeArray()` should reallocate more memory. But instead Im getting this output from the `resizeArray()`:

```
printf("The memory heap is exhausted!\n");
```

What did I do wrong in the code?

```
typedef struct Location {
    char locName[35];
    char locDesc[85];
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
} LocationArray;

int main() {
    printf("How many locations would you like to be inside the array?\n");
    int numberOfLoc = 0; //variable for storing the size of the LocationArray
    scanf(" %d", &numberOfLoc); //gets the user input and stores in numerOfLoc

    LocationArray* myArray; //declares a LocationArray with the size of numberOfLoc
    myArray = (LocationArray*)malloc(numberOfLoc * sizeof(LocationArray));

    int count = 0;
    while(1) {
        //Prints the menu
        printMenu(&myArray, &count, &numberOfLoc);
    }
    //Free the pointer
    free(myArray);
    return 0;
}

void addInfo(LocationArray** myArray, int* count, int* numberOfLoc) {

    if(*count == *numberOfLoc) { // Checks if the array is already full
        printf("count is %d and numberOfLoc is %d\n", *count, *numberOfLoc);
        resizeArray(myArray, numberOfLoc); //Resizes the array if it's full
    }
    .......
    (*count)++;
}

void resizeArray(LocationArray** myArray, int* numberOfLoc) {
    *numberOfLoc = *numberOfLoc * 2; //Double the size

    LocationArray* temp;
    temp = (LocationArray*)realloc(myArray, *numberOfLoc * sizeof(LocationArray)); //Reallocates more memory

    //Checks if the memory heap is exhausted
    if(temp == NULL) {
        printf("The memory heap is exhausted!\n");
    }
    else {
        *myArray = temp; //Copy from the temp struct variable to myArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resizeArray() takes `LocationArray **`, but addInfo() passes `LocationArray *` to it, so you end up passing garbage to realloc().

Comment: Tried that, still the same result @keithmo

Comment: Try that AND remove the free() in resizeArray.

Comment: Could you please check if `*numberOfLoc = *numberOfLoc * (*numberOfLoc);` doubles the size of `numberOfLoc`, @keithmo?

Comment: No, it's going to square the number. Doubling is probably a fine strategy, squaring is extreme. Also, you need to do this BEFORE the realloc().

Comment: sorry but last question and it started to giving`"The memory heap is exhausted!"` again . Its not reallocating memory. I've updated the code for `resizeArray()`. Could you please take a look? @keithmo

Comment: `temp = (LocationArray*)realloc(myArray, *numberOfLoc *sizeof(LocationArray));` should be `temp = (LocationArray*)realloc(*myArray, *numberOfLoc *sizeof(LocationArray));` (note `*myArray`).

Comment: Thank you a lot! Im still fighting with the pointers in C and hopefully will grasp them eventually. @keithmo

Answer (score 2):

I see one problem straight up:

```
*myArray = temp; //Copy from the temp struct variable to myArray
free(*myArray);
```

I don't think you should be doing that, since `temp` is the newly allocated memory which you then place into `*myArray` then free it immediately.

Additionally, since both `resizeArray` and `addInfo` take a variable of type `LocationArray **`, you probably want to pass it through as-is. In other words, the last line of `addInfo` should be:

```
resizeArray (myArray, numberOfLoc);
```

It's also not a good idea to blindly ignore return codes from functions that use them to indicate failure.

Comment: You're right -- the free is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Should I remove `free()`?, @paxdiablo

Comment: @John, yes, `realloc` will free the original memory if needed (and if the reallocation works).

Comment: Could you please check if `*numberOfLoc = *numberOfLoc * (*numberOfLoc);` doubles the size of `numberOfLoc`, @paxdiablo?

Comment: @paxdiablo, sorry but last question and it started to giving`"The memory heap is exhausted!"` again . Its not reallocating memory. I've updated the code for `resizeArray()`. Could you please take a look?